# Windows swap file offset to page entry translation

Tags: windows, memory, kernel, swapfile

How can i determine by sector(or cluster) number in windows swap file what page is swapped out to this disk sectors range?

Of course, if this sectors(cluster) isn't mapped to any page and it's free i want to know it too.

May be i can do this with Windows Kernel Debugger somehow?

Comment: Still trying to come up with any legitimate reason you might want to do this.....

Comment: I got out of sync blocks on mirrored storage that contains virtual drives of windows virtual machines. Hypervisor is KVM. Out of sync blocks in windows VM's swap files sectors ranges. So i try to understand why it isn't synced. I understand why it is possible, but to prove it i need information about page to swap mappings in windows kernel.